# able to insert parquet file in bucket, but not in a specific folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to load a parquet file in my AWS s3, when i am inserting it in the bucket directly, the code is working fit and fine. But, when I give a specific file path of a folder no insertion of file happen.

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

access_key='**'
secret_key='**/**'

# Initialize a Boto3 session
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
)

# Creating an S3 resource
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

# converting dataframe(data) into parquet
out_buffer = io.BytesIO()
data.to_parquet(out_buffer, index=False)

# passing S3 bucket and object path
bucket = 'stag'
object_path = 'test.parquet'

# Upload the Parquet file to S3
s3_resource.Object(bucket, object_path).put(Body=out_buffer.getvalue())

# Close the buffer
out_buffer.close()
```

This code works good, but when i give a folder path and name of file in the object_path variable, no insertion of file happen

please, help here to insert the file in a specific folder path

Comment: "give a folder path and name of file in the object_path" - what exact paths and name are you using?

Comment: thanks alot its working, i was making a mistake of giving bucket name in object_path.